# Problems accessing Tkinter widgets in a list

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to write a small program where I have a list of Labels and Entry-fields using Python and Tkinter (see code below). Adding the widgets is no problem. However, when I want to use a method of one of the instances (like Insert() on one of the Entry-fields) I can't figure out a way to do it.

My code looks like this:

```
from Tkinter import *
import random
root = Tk()

attributes = {'Strength':10, 'Dexterity':10, 'Constitution':10, 'Intelligence':10, 'wisdom':10, 'charisma':10}
entries = []
labels = []

i = 0
for a in attributes:
   labels.append(Label(root, text = a, justify = LEFT).grid(sticky = W))
   entries.append(Entry(root).grid(column = 1, row = i))
   i = i+1

root.mainloop()
```

and I have tried a simple

```
entries[i].insert("text to insert")
```

and

```
e = Entry
e = entries[i]
e.insert...
```

but it hasn't helped. I've seen other examples of people trying to use an object in a list, and it seems they are just doing as I did in my first attempt. Have I missed something?

Thanks

Comment: What you missed is the error message. What is it telling you? If ypu take that error message literally, what does it lead you to discover?

Answer (score 6):

`Entry(root).grid()` returns a `NoneType` object, so all you are storing in your list is `None`.  You can create the `Entry` widget first, call `grid()` and then append it to your list.

```
from Tkinter import *
import random
root = Tk()
attributes = {'Strength':10, 'Dexterity':10, 'Constitution':10, 'Intelligence':10, 'wisdom':10, 'charisma':10}
entries = []
labels = []


for i,a in enumerate(attributes):
   labels.append(Label(root, text = a, justify = LEFT).grid(sticky = W))
   e = Entry(root)
   e.grid(column=1, row=i)
   entries.append(e)
   entries[i].insert(INSERT,"text to insert")



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! That was it (I should have figured really.. I did a print entries, and all i got was (none, none... ))

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem before when I started Python. I was like, "Why take up two lines creating something and setting the grid location. I'll put it all on one." Funny story, the '.grid' returns None. So I don't think you're actually appending anything here.

Comment: Yupp, that was it... see my comment above, I should have figured. Thanks